How Can I Design a Grip for Holding Skewer Sticks in a CNC Machine? (vid inside)
I'm working on a project where I need to securely hold wooden skewer sticks in a CNC machine. The smooth surface of the skewers makes it challenging to create a reliable grip that ensures they don't slip or move during the process.
To give you a better idea of what I’m aiming for, I’ve attached an image and a video of an industrial robot with a similar grip mechanism that I’m trying to replicate. My goal is to adapt something like this for my CNC setup.
Has anyone here tackled a similar challenge? I’m looking for suggestions on how to design or create a grip that I can incorporate into the CNC machine. I’m especially interested in any DIY solutions or specific materials that work well for this purpose.
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
Youtube link: https://youtu.be/TyjhT0GK1iI?si=1qPEEdtFuUpc9lws&t=116

don't slip or move during the process ... what is the process?

There's grip firmer, and grip better. Firmer seems little more than upping the gripping force (pneumatic pressure, whatever). Better means less slippage for a given grip strength. That suggests gripping surfaces with better friction, or that bite into the skewer stick more. You didn't specify, but I assume the robot doesn't care if there are "bite" marks on the sticks? Then maybe a more assertively textured grip surface would help, perhaps like garage pliers.
